# Getting the error ModuleNotFoundError at / No module named 'sekizai'

Tags: python, django, django-sekizai

I'm having this error in browsers in production after attempting to install the module django-sezikai.

---

python version 3.7.9 ;
django version 2.1.15 ;
OS: CentOS

---

[image: snip from browser]

I removed the module from settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs [here](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

There are another settings that refer to `sekizai` like `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Try to grep for `sekizai` on the codebase.

Comment: can't find anything with grep and there is nothing in the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Comment: then try cleaning ```.pyc``` files

Comment: tried that but didn't work, however, the error is gone after rebooting the server. Thanks for your help